# Ubuntu MaaS ssl error vmware vcenter 6 connection

Tags: ubuntu, python, vmware

My setup:

- Ubuntu Server 16.04.1
- MaaS 2.0 Beta 3
- vmware vcenter 6

`pyvmomi-5.5.0.2014.1.1` which is installed manually for Python 3 because I read it would fix my problem.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Aug 1 13:21:26 maas sh[5319]: 2016-08-01 13:21:25 [-] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:794: requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html

Aug 1 13:21:26 maas maas.rpc.cluster: [ERROR] Failed to probe and enlist VMware nodes: (vim.fault.HostConnectFault) {#012 dynamicType = ,#012 dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],#012 msg = '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)',#012 faultCause = ,#012 faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) []#012}
```

I read several old posts from last year on how on to fix that but none of them work or even point me to the files which I have to edit.

Somebody please point me in the right direction so that i can deploy my VMWare nodes.

I tried MaaS 1.8/1.9 and now 2.0 and each version has problems that cannot be solved or are solved in future version but bring now bugs with it.

Answer (score 1):

I filed [bug #1608639](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maas/+bug/1608639) on Launchpad for this, and the solution posted there worked for me.

Downloading the self-signed certificates from your VMware system and configuring your system to consider them trusted should work. The process I use for this is as follows:

```
$ sudo -i
# openssl s_client -connect 10.230.8.210:443 -showcerts < /dev/null
# mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/custom
# nano /usr/share/ca-certificates/custom/vmware.crt
<paste certificate>
# dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

Note, however, that this only works if the self-signed SSL certificate for the VMware system has a properly configured common name (or subject alternate name) so that the SSL library can match the IP address or hostname to the connection string.

In MAAS 2.x, you can work around this issue by adjusting the power parameters for your VMware servers. In our lab environments, we use the following command line to add a VMware chassis:

```
maas profile machines add-chassis chassis_type=vmware username=vmware-username password=vmware-password protocol='https+unverified' hostname=vmware-api-ip-address prefix_filter=maas
```

(This will add all VMs named "maas*" to MAAS.)

Comment: If you had taken the time to look at the edit history of your question you would see how easy it is not to make your question look ugly.